# GTK GLib errors

Tags: 11.10, graphics, gtk, themes, glib

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 from 11.04 I get GTK and GLib errors while trying to run a kernel menuconfig using OpenEmbedded.

I'm asking it here as I think these errors are caused by some change from 11.04 to 11.10 version, not because of the specific issue with OpenEmbedded.

Here's an example of the errors I get:

```
| (gnome-terminal:19575): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1230:46: Couldn't recognize the image file format for file '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/slider.png'
| (gnome-terminal:19575): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.system.proxy' is not installed
| (gnome-terminal:19575): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_va: assertion `value != NULL' failed
| (gnome-terminal:19575): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_font_description_from_string: assertion `str != NULL' failed
```

Interestingly, if I change my Gnome theme from Ambiance (which uses png images) to High Contrast, the first type of error disappears.

Any experience with these compatibility issues?

Answer (score 1):

I also experience the same problem with Ubuntu 11.10.  OE devshell worked for me with 11.04.  I got around the problem by adding

```
TERMCMD = ${XTERM_TERMCMD}
TERMCMDRUN = ${XTERM_TERMCMDRUN}
```

in my local.conf.

Comment: I tried it but I still get the same error when I launch "bitbake -c menuconfig linux-at91sam9x5ek", where linux-at91sam9x5ek is the name of my distro